"Paste on page" shortcut in inkscape missing
I can't seem to find Paste on Page shortcut anywhere in the preferences>interface>keyboard to assign it a shortcut.

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There's no short cut for that, and no way to add one. It's not in the list.

That's a shame - thanks for confirming. Do you know why it was excluded?

Multi-page functionality is fairly new in Inkscape, so they probably haven't got round to adding a shortcut for it yet.  Instead you can add and snap a rectangle shape to the top left corner of the page you are copying from. Then select that object, plus the one you want to copy. Then on the other page, just paste as normal, and click and drag to snap to the corner of that page. Delete the extra shapes afterwards.

Thanks @BillyKerr, you are correct that these steps would lead to the desired effect :) I trust that it won't come as a surprise however if I say that if you have to repeat this action 100 times a day it's not... the most practical...

If you want the shortcut to be included, perhaps suggest it over at the Inkscape GitLab site.  That's really the only way to hopefully get them to add it.

Might also suggest if you find yourself doing stuff like this a lot, where you need certain elements on every page in the same position, Inkscape might not be the best tool for this. It's not really page layout software, unlike for example Scribus which has master page functionality.

True, submitted: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/10342
